# Import .jsx files with SystemJS

Tags: babeljs, systemjs

Since the JSX plugin is deprecated I've been struggling to have Babel handle my jsx files. I finally managed to convince SystemJS to load my app with:

```
 System.import('scripts/app.jsx!babel')
```

But this doesn't import any imported jsx files like:

```
import Login from './components/Login'  // File is Login.jsx
```

With the old plugin this worked but now I am not sure how to get it working now.

Answer (score -1):

One step in the right direction would be adding this to your config:

```
"packages": {
    "components": { // Packages could of course be replaced with what you want
                    // to affect. Even "." is valid.
        meta: {
            '*.jsx': {
                loader: 'babel'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to load files as such: `import .. from './components/Login.jsx'`.

You could take this one step further by adding `"defaultExtension": "jsx"` under `"components"`. I'd only use this if the folder/modules was jsx-only though. That would allow you to import as `import .. from './components/Login'` as you wanted to.